# There is interlude and read login page before enter to admin page flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to make my app if has logged in will enter the admin page but there are interlude a seconds and read login page before entering to the admin page. What should I do? If I put loading before enter it when/what cycle loading will stop?
Here is it my code

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isLoggedIn = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _checkIfLoggedIn();
    super.initState();
  }


  void _checkIfLoggedIn() async {
    // check if token is there
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = localStorage.getString('api_token');
    if(token!= null){
      setState(() {
        _isLoggedIn = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        textTheme:GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(textTheme).copyWith(
          body1: GoogleFonts.montserrat(textStyle: textTheme.body1),
        ),
      ),
      home:
      _isLoggedIn ?
      AdminMain()
          :
      LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put is loading first and in initstate I set _isLoggedin true first and then _isLoading false

```
_isLoading ? loadingWidget(context)
      :
      (_isLoggedIn ?
      AdminMain()
          :
      LoginPage()
      ),
```